# Clean, simple function factories in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

**Short example.** I am exploring the behavior of a function by testing it with different "specs", `f(spec)`. I wrote down one spec by hand, `spec1`, and am creating new specs as variations on it. To do this, I decided to write a function:

```
spec1 = list(fy = list(a = 1), fx = list(f1 = function(x) 10-x, f2 = function(x) 2-x))

make_spec = function(f = function(x) 10-x, xtheta = 2)
    list(fy = list(a = 1), fx = list(f1 = f, f2 = function(x) xtheta-x))

res1 = make_spec()

# first problem: they don't match

    all.equal(res1,spec1)
    # [1] "Component “fx”: Component “f2”: target, current do not match when deparsed"
    # ^ this happens, even though...
    res1$fx$f2(4) == spec1$fx$f2(4)
    # TRUE

# second problem: res1 is fugly

    res1
    # $fy
    # $fy$a
    # [1] 1
    # 
    # 
    # $fx
    # $fx$f1
    # function (x) 
    # 10 - x
    # <environment: 0x000000000f8f2e20>
    # 
    # $fx$f2
    # function (x) 
    # xtheta - x
    # <environment: 0x000000000f8f2e20>

    str(res1)
    # even worse
```

My goals for `make_spec` are...

1. `all.equal(spec1, res1)` and/or `identical(spec1, res1)`
2. for `str(res1)` to be human-readable  (no `<environment: ptr>` tags or `srcfilecopy`)
3. to avoid `substitute` and `eval` altogether if possible (not a high priority)
4. to avoid writing out the second arg of `substitute` (see "full" example below)

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve some or all of these goals?

---

**Full example.** I'm not sure if the example above fully covers my use case, so here's the latter:

```
spec0 = list(
    v_dist = list(
        pdf  = function(x) 1,
        cdf  = function(x) x,
        q    = function(x) x,
        supp = c(0,1)
    )
    ,
    ucondv_dist = {
        ucondv_dist = list()
        ucondv_dist$condmean    = function(v) 10-v
        ucondv_dist$pdf         = function(u,v) dnorm(u, ucondv_dist$condmean(v), 50)
        ucondv_dist$cdf         = function(u,v) pnorm(u, ucondv_dist$condmean(v), 50)
        ucondv_dist
    }
)

make_spec = function(ycondx_condmean = function(x) 10-x, ycondx_sd = 50){

  s = substitute(list(
    x_dist = list(
      pdf  = function(x) 1,
      cdf  = function(x) x,
      q  = function(x) x,
      supp = c(0,1)
    )
    ,
    ycondx_dist = {
      ycondx_dist = list()
      ycondx_dist$condmean  = ycondx_condmean
      ycondx_dist$pdf     = function(u,v) dnorm(u, ycondx_dist$condmean(v), ycondx_sd)
      ycondx_dist$cdf     = function(u,v) pnorm(u, ycondx_dist$condmean(v), ycondx_sd)
      ycondx_dist
    }
  )
  , list(ycondx_condmean=ycondx_condmean, ycondx_sd = ycondx_sd))

  eval(s, .GlobalEnv)
}

res0 = make_spec()
```

---

**Side note**. I don't know if "function factory" is the right term here, since I am not a computer scientist, but it seems related. I found only [a paragraph on the concept related to R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures).

Comment: Actually it appears you just don't like R and are really looking for another language, Scala or erlang perhaps.. The `str` function is fairly complex but you are certainly welcome to rewrite it. That would be an large project, well above what would be a reasonable SO question. The notion of trying to program on the language without using `eval` and `substitute` seems perverse and nowhere justified.

Comment: @42- Thanks for the feedback. Well, avoiding `eval` and `substitute` is low on my list of priorities, but if I'm just stupidly overlooking some way of avoiding them, I'd like to know it.

Comment: you can get part 1 (clumsily because you return more than just a function) using `library(pryr)`, `res1$fx <- lapply(res1$fx,unenclose)`, `all.equal(res1,spec1)`

Comment: @Chris Oh that's handy, thanks! I'll have to look into that package some more.

Comment: you can read more on this at the link you posted actually. As @jenesaisquoi suggests, the strange printing (and all.equal) behaviour is because of how R functions and closures use environments.

Answer (score 3):

The enclosing environments of the functions are different leading to the difference in output/difference in deparsing.  So, there are two things to do to get the desired output:

- make the environments the same
- substitute the variables from the enclosing environments into the function bodies.

However, doing it this way you get a double dose of the eval/substitute you didn't want, so maybe there would be an alternative.

```
make_spec <- function(f = function(x) 10-x, xtheta = 2) {
  e <- parent.frame()
  fixClosure <- function(func)
    eval(eval(substitute(substitute(func)), parent.frame()), e)

  list(fy = list(a = 1), fx = list(
    f1 = fixClosure(f), 
    f2 = fixClosure(function(x) xtheta-x)
  ))
}

spec1 <- list(fy = list(a = 1), fx = list(f1 = function(x) 10-x, f2 = function(x) 2-x))
res1 <- make_spec()

all.equal(res1, spec1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with the eval and substitute as used here and like this approach. Going to leave the question open a while, since I won't have the chance to apply any solutions to my original problem for a while.